# Drawer no funcionar hasta que recargo mi archivo context

Tags: react-native

estoy creando una mini app para ventas de abarrotes, y estoy implementando drawer el cual me genera un conflicto a la hora de loguearme la segunda vez, este no aparece hasta que  recargo el archivo context

```
    import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
    import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import MaterialCommunityIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import * as eva from "@eva-design/eva";
    import {
      ApplicationProvider,
      Layout,
      IconRegistry,
      Button,
      Icon,
    } from "@ui-kitten/components";
    import { EvaIconsPack } from "@ui-kitten/eva-icons";
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
    import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
    import { default as mapping } from "./mapping.json";
    import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
    import HomeScreen from "./components/HomeScreen";
    import Products from "./components/Products";
    import Offert from "./components/Offert";
    import Favorites from "./components/Favorites";
    import MyAccount from "./components/MyAccount";
    import ModalBimbo from "./modalScreen/Bimbo";
    import Login from "./components/Login";
    import UpdateUser from "./modalScreen/UpdateUser";
    import { Register } from "./modalScreen/Register";
    import { StateProvider, useMyContext } from "./appContext/appContext";
    import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
    import { Loading } from "./components/Loading";
    import { RenderProducts } from "./components/RenderProducts";
    import { Title } from "react-native-paper";

    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

    function MyTabs({ navigation }) {
      const [token, setToken] = useState();

      const getToken = async () => {
        try {
          const tokenStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@token");
          setToken(tokenStorage);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };

      const IconRender = () => {
        return token ? (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="account-edit"
            color="white"
            size={36}
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.push("UpdateUser");
            }}
          />
        ) : null;
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        getToken();
      });
      return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Tiendita de la Esquina"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
              tabBarLabel: "Home",
              tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={30} />
              ),
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Productos"
            component={Products}
            options={{
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "red",
              },
              headerTintColor: "#fff",
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: "bold",
              },
              tabBarLabel: "Productos",
              tabBarActiveTintColor: "gray",
              tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" },
              tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="shopping-search"
                  color={color}
                  size={30}
                />
              ),
            }}
          />

          <Tab.Screen
            name="Ofertas"
            component={Offert}
            options={{
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "red",
              },
              headerTintColor: "#fff",
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: "bold",
              },
              tabBarLabel: "Productos",
              tabBarActiveTintColor: "gray",
              tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" },
              tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="tag" color={color} size={30} />
              ),
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Favoritos"
            component={Favorites}
            options={{
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "red",
              },
              headerTintColor: "#fff",
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: "bold",
              },
              tabBarLabel: "Productos",
              tabBarActiveTintColor: "gray",
              tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" },
              tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="heart" color={color} size={30} />
              ),
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Mi Cuenta"
            component={MyAccount}
            options={({ navigation }) => ({
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "red",
              },
              headerTintColor: "#fff",
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: "bold",
              },
              tabBarLabel: "Mi Cuenta",
              tabBarActiveTintColor: "gray",
              tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" },
              tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={30} />
                ),
                headerRight: () => <IconRender />,
            })}
          />
        
        </Tab.Navigator>
      );
    }

    function DrawerStackScreen() {
      return (
        <Drawer.Navigator 
          initialRouteName="MyTabs"
          screenOptions={{
            
          }}  
        >
          <Drawer.Screen name="MyTabs" component={MyTabs} />
          
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      );
    }
    export default function App() {
      const [fontLoaded] = useFonts({
        Bela: require("./assets/fonts/Belanosima-SemiBold.ttf"),
        BelaRegular: require("./assets/fonts/Belanosima-Regular.ttf"),
        Poppins: require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf"),
      });
      if (!fontLoaded) return null;
      return (
        <StateProvider>
          <>
            <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
            <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light} customMapping={mapping}>
              <NavigationContainer style={styles.container}>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                  <Stack.Screen
                   name="DrawerStack" // Puedes darle el nombre que desees
                   component={DrawerStackScreen}
                   options={{ headerShown: false }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                   name="Loading"
                   component={Loading}
                   options={{ headerShown: false }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                   name="RenderProducts"
                   component={RenderProducts}
                   options={{ headerShown: false }}
                  />
                   <Stack.Screen
                   name="MyTabs"
                   component={MyTabs}
                   options={{ headerShown: false }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="Login"
                    component={Login}
                    options={({ navigation }) => ({
                      title: "  Bienvenido",
                      headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: "red",
                      },
                      headerTintColor: "#fff",
                      headerTitleStyle: {
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                      },
                      headerLeft: () => (
                        <Icon
                          style={styles.icon}
                          fill="#fff"
                          name="arrow-back-outline"
                          onPress={() => {
                            navigation.navigate("MyTabs");
                          }}
                        />
                      ),
                    })}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="HomeScreen"
                    component={HomeScreen}
                    options={{ headerShown: false }}
                  />

                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="Register"
                    component={Register}
                    options={({ navigation }) => ({
                      title: "Registro",
                      headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: "red",
                      },
                      headerTintColor: "#fff",
                      headerTitleStyle: {
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                      },
                      headerLeft: () => (
                        <Icon
                          style={styles.icon}
                          fill="#fff"
                          name="arrow-back-outline"
                          onPress={() => {
                            navigation.navigate("MyTabs");
                          }}
                        />
                      ),
                    })}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="ModalBimbo"
                    component={ModalBimbo}
                    options={({ navigation }) => ({
                      title: "Bimbo",
                      headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: "red",
                      },
                      headerTintColor: "#fff",
                      headerTitleStyle: {
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                      },
                      headerLeft: () => (
                        <Icon
                          style={styles.icon}
                          fill="#fff"
                          name="arrow-back-outline"
                          onPress={() => {
                            navigation.navigate("MyTabs");
                          }}
                        />
                      ),
                    })}
                    />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="UpdateUser"
                    component={UpdateUser}
                    options={({ navigation }) => ({
                      title: "Actualizar Datos",
                      headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: "red",
                      },
                      headerTintColor: "#fff",
                      headerTitleStyle: {
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                      },
                      headerLeft: () => (
                        <Icon
                          style={styles.icon}
                          fill="#fff"
                          name="arrow-back-outline"
                          onPress={() => {
                            navigation.navigate("MyTabs");
                          }}
                        />
                      ),
                    })}
                  ></Stack.Screen>
                </Stack.Navigator>
                <StatusBar style="auto" />
              </NavigationContainer>
            </ApplicationProvider>
          </>
        </StateProvider>
      );
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      },
      icon: {
        width: 32,
        height: 32,
      },
    });
    import React, { createContext, useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
    export const StateContext = createContext(null);
    import axios from 'axios';
    //import { API_URL} from '@env';

    export const useMyContext = () => useContext(StateContext);

    export const StateProvider = ({ children,navigation }) => {
     const [user, setUser] = useState('');
     const [password, setpassword] = useState('')
     const [token,setToken] = useState('')
     const [uid, setUid] = useState()
     const [imagen, setImagen] = useState({})
     const [productos, setProductos] = useState({})
     const [name, setName] = useState("")

      const login =  () => {
        return axios.post('https://abarrotes.msalazar.dev/user/login?_format=json', {
        "name": user,
        "pass": password,
          headers : {
          "Content-Type" : "application/json",
          },
        })
        .then(async function (response) {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem("@UID",response.data.current_user.uid)
          return response.status
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error, "error de logueo")
        });

      }

      const getToken = () => {
         return axios.post('https://abarrotes.msalazar.dev/session/token?_format=json', {
          headers : {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json",
          },
        }).then( async res=>{
            console.log(res.data)
            return res.data
        }).catch(err=>{
          console.log(err)
        })
      }

      const getUid = async () => {
       const uidUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@UID")
       getDataUser(uidUser)
      }

      const userRemove= async()=> {
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@name")
          console.log("user eliminado")
        } catch(error) {
          console.log(error, "error en el catech")
        }
      }

      const tokenDelete=async()=> {
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@token")
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      } 

      const getProveedores = () => {
        axios.get('https://abarrotes.msalazar.dev/jsonapi/node/img_proveedores?include=field_img_proveedores', {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          setImagen(response.data)
          setProductos(response.data.data)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });  
      }

      const getDataUser = async (uid)=> {
      
        console.log(uid, "uid")
        await axios.get(`https://abarrotes.msalazar.dev/user/` + uid + `?_format=json`, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json",
          },
        }).then(async(response) =>{
           //console.log(response.data)
          //setUidStorage(response.data.uid[0].value)
          //setApellidoUser(response.data.field_apellidos_usuario[0].value)
          //setDireccionUser(response.data.field_direccion_usuario[0].value)
          //setTelefonoUser(response.data.field_telefono_usuario[0].value)
          //setEmailUser(response.data.field_email_usuario[0].value)
          await AsyncStorage.setItem("@name", response.data.field_nombre_usuario[0].value) 
          const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@name');
          console.log(value, "name" )
          if(value !== null) {
            setName(value)
          }
          // await AsyncStorage.setItem("@lastname", response.data.field_apellidos_usuario[0].value)
          // await AsyncStorage.setItem("@address", response.data.field_direccion_usuario[0].value)
          // await AsyncStorage.setItem("@email", response.data.field_email_usuario[0].value)
          // await AsyncStorage.setItem("@phone", response.data.field_telefono_usuario[0].value)
        })
      }

     
       

      



      useEffect(()=>{
       getProveedores()
       getUid()
      },[])

      return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={{
         setToken,
         setUser,
         setpassword,
         tokenDelete,
         userRemove,
         login,
         getToken,
         getProveedores,
         getUid,
         user,
         password,
         imagen,
         productos,
         name,
         
        }}>
          {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
      );
    };




La verdad intente  renderizar context retornando todo el componente  para que cada que cargara app.js forazara a contex, despues use funciones de context en app para forzarlo y nada, tambien quise ejecutar mydrawer component en useffect de context sin ningun resultado, la verdad ya no tengo ideas, si alguien me puede orientar seria de gran ayuda.
```

de echo  la funcion login se ejecuta en un componente llamado login el cual lo ejecuto de esta manera

```
  const loginBtn = async () => {
    let status = await login()
     if (status == 200) {
       navigation.navigate("MyTabs")
     }
  }
```

loginbtn se ejecuta en el HTML,  si la respuesta es 200 entonces renderiza a este componente  espero de verdad que me puedan ayudar porque ya no tengo idea de como hacerlo, se me acabaron las ideas